# How to calculate a length of a line from a point of crossing of two lines

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's say I have a line $l$:

$$l: ax+by=c$$
And I have a line segment $s$ of length $d$ which is perpendicular to the line $l$ and the start point of this line segment $s$ lies on the line $l$ (let's denote the start point of $s$ as $P$).

How can I find a length of a line which is parallel to $y$ axis and starts at point $P$ and its end point has the same $y$ coordinate as the end point of the line segment $s$.

Here is a picture of what I mean: [picture of a problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9djW.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's work with your figure. Denote $\Delta$$PQR$ where $Q$ is the point of the line segment $s$ with length $d$ not on the line $l$. $PR$ is the line you wish to find the length of.

Now you can see that $\Delta$$PQR$ is a right angle triangle. $\angle$$PRQ$ is $90$$^\circ$. Now we also see by simple angle chasing, that $\angle$$QPR$ is the same $\theta$ as the angle made by the line $l$ with the x-axis. Hence,

$tan$$\theta$ = $a/b$. Where $\theta$ is clearly the acute angle for your figure assuming $a,b>0$.

Now, by simple trigonometry $PR = PQ$ $cos$$\theta$.

Here $cos$$\theta$ = $\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}$

Hence $PR = \frac{db}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}$. Which is your required length.